# consecutive characters, rewrite function for output be dataframe instead of np.array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i am trying to rewrite a function which inputs and output are a `np.array` to be one which input and output a `DataFrame`. My function is :

```
def number_of_consecutive_or_identical_characters(email) -> np.array:
    encoded = [list(ord(char) for char in email[0]) for email in email]
    distances = [np.diff(e) for e in encoded]
    return np.array([sum(1 for x in d if np.abs(x) < 1) for d in distances]).reshape(-1, 1)
```

So whenever i pass something like this

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'email': ['AAABBB@gmAil.com', 'KINNNGKING@gmail.com']})
number_of_consecutive_or_identical_characters(a.values)
```

i get

```
array([[6],
       [2]])
```

now i want to result be

[image]

if i pass

```
number_of_consecutive_or_identical_characters(a)
```

i was starting like this but i was not even to write the encoded variable right :(

```
def number_of_consecutive_or_identical_characters(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    encoded = (df["email"]
                 .str.split("@")
                 .str[0]
                 .apply(lambda x: ord(c) for c in x)
                 )

    print(encoded)
    return encoded
```

Comment: `np.array()` makes a numpy array.  `pd.DataFrame()` makes a data frame.  Documentation for both functions is easy to find.  What's your difficulty?

Comment: The return value is `[[4] [2]]` with your sample code.